# trying to calculate vectors with java

Tags: java, math, vector

I had a quick question about java math and a little bit about math in general. so 763.5*cos(70) should in equal to 261.13237 that's how the Ax vector is calculated, however, in java the answer seems to be 483.53921155638994. no idea why. any help is much appreciated

here is what I have so far

```
package Main;  
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class vectors{
    
           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double Mag = 763.5;
        double Deg = 70;
        double Ax;
        double Ay;
        
        Ax = Mag*Math.cos(Deg);
        
        System.out.println(Ax);
        
        
        

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.cos()'s argument is in radians:

```java
        double Mag = 763.5;                                                     
        double Deg = 70;                                                        
        double radians = (Deg / 360) * 2 * Math.PI;                             
        double Ax;                                                              
        double Ay;                                                              
                                                                                
        Ax = Mag*Math.cos(radians);                                             
                                                                                
        System.out.println(Ax);
```

`261.13237942914816`

Comment: You can also do `double radians = Math.toRadians(Deg);`